# YYIIS Inflation swap chapter 16 of Brigo's text

Tags: swaps, inflation, payoff

Are there errata in the Brigos's text of Interest Rate Models in chapter 16 when it is defined the YYIIS payoff? In formula (16.3) is defined Party A's payoff as:

\begin{align}
\\
N\psi_i\left[\frac{I\left(T_i\right)}{I\left(T_{i-1}\right)}-1\right]
\\
\end{align}

Where $\psi_i$ is the floating-leg year fraction for the interval $\left[T_{i-1},T_i\right]$

I think that CPI rentability is not annualized so we do not need $\psi_{i}$ factor in order to calculate the period rentability in terms of an annual rentability. Isn't it? I am not sure because these possible errata are in the following pages of the chapter...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation I see is that the natural periodicity of this product is annual and that the fraction of a year is practically 1, so multiplying it by the fraction of a year is motivated by the day count conventions agreements between party A and party B.